# Python, como validar se a variável é None?

Tags: python, django

Não estou conseguindo verificar se a variável não possui valor (None)

View:

```
endereco_id = request.POST.get('endereco_id', None)
if formCliente.is_valid() and formEndereco.is_valid():
    print('********** endereco_id **************')
    print(endereco_id)
    print('************************')
    if endereco_id:
       formEndereco.instance= Endereco.objects.get(id=endereco_id)
```

O print:

```
********** endereco_id **************
None
************************
```

Por que está entrando no IF se no print o valor da variável é None?

Tentativas:

```
if endereco_id != None:
     formEndereco.instance= Endereco.objects.get(id=endereco_id)

if endereco_id is not None: 
     formEndereco.instance= Endereco.objects.get(id=endereco_id)
```

Nada funcionou, onde estou errando? A versão do Python é a 3.5 com Django 1.10.

No Shell funciona:

```
>>> endereco_id=None
>>> if endereco_id:
...     print('Possui valor')
... else:
...     print('É None')
... 
É None
>>> endereco_id=1
>>> if endereco_id:
...     print('Possui valor')
... else:
...     print('É None')
... 
Possui valor
>>>
```

View:

```
def novo_cliente(request):

    formCliente = ClienteForm(request.POST or None)
    formEndereco = EnderecoForm(request.POST or None)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        cliente_id = request.POST.get('cliente_id', None)
        endereco_id = request.POST.get('endereco_id', None)

        if formCliente.is_valid() and formEndereco.is_valid():
            if endereco_id is not None:
                formEndereco.instance= Endereco.objects.get(id=endereco_id)

            if cliente_id is not None:
                formCliente.instance= Cliente.objects.get(id=cliente_id)

            novo_endereco = formEndereco.save()
            novo_cliente = formCliente.save(commit=False)
            novo_cliente.endereco = novo_endereco
            novo_cliente.save()

            return redirect('appOrcamento:edit_cliente', orcamento.id)


    context = {
        'formCliente':formCliente,
        'formEndereco':formEndereco,
        }

    return render(request, 'appOrcamento/novo_cliente.html', context)
```

Comment: Edilson, obrigado pela sugestão.  Mesmo a variável sendo None, entrou no else.

Comment: Sim, eu só incluí o else para testar a sua sugestão.  Eu realmente só tenho uma linha que deve ser processada caso o endereco_id seja diferente de None.

Comment: Edilson, eu já tentei com o is not None, porém não tive sucesso.  Mesmo a variável estando None, entra no if.  Fiz o mesmo teste no shell e funcionou.  Será que o erro é porque estou recuperando o valor do POST?  endereco_id = request.POST.get('endereco_id', None)

Comment: O código é extenso, caso não coloca-o no pastebin, ou outro repositório qualquer para que possa ver.

Comment: Coloquei o view na pergunta.

Comment: E qual seria o `else` aí ? Já usaste `if not defined_id` ou mesmo `if defined_id == None` ? Porque deve tudo retornar falso quando se usa com o `if`, seja None, False ou String vazia.

Comment: O else não existe.  Se o endereco_id possuir valor, preciso recuperar o endereco o mesmo acontece para o cliente_id.

Comment: Certo, já experimentaste os exemplos que apresentei neste último comentário ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57137/discussion-between-developer-and-edilson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com ajuda do @Edilson, conseguimos identificar o problema.  É básico, porém para quem está iniciando em Python com Django, pode se tornar complicado.  Por este motivo vou explicar o que ocorreu.

Ao recuperar o valor de um campo no POST na view, caso o campo não exista no template o retorno é None, ou seja, não existe o campo, seria o null.  Quando o campo existe no template, mas se estiver sem informação o retorno no posto é um str 'None'.

Esse foi o meu problema, no print estava sendo impresso None, porém era do tipo str e o if não funcionava corretamente.

Ex.:

cliente_id = request.POST.get('cliente_id', None)

Caso cliente_id não exista  no template, o retorno será None (null)

Caso cliente_id exista no template, porém sem valor, o retorno será um str 'None'

A solução:

```
def novo_cliente(request):

    formCliente = ClienteForm(request.POST or None)
    formEndereco = EnderecoForm(request.POST or None)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        cliente_id = request.POST.get('cliente_id', None)
        endereco_id = request.POST.get('endereco_id', None)

        if formCliente.is_valid() and formEndereco.is_valid():
            if endereco_id != 'None':
                formEndereco.instance= Endereco.objects.get(id=endereco_id)

            if cliente_id != 'None':
                formCliente.instance= Cliente.objects.get(id=cliente_id)

            novo_endereco = formEndereco.save()
            novo_cliente = formCliente.save(commit=False)
            novo_cliente.endereco = novo_endereco
            novo_cliente.save()

            return redirect('appOrcamento:edit_cliente', orcamento.id)


    context = {
        'formCliente':formCliente,
        'formEndereco':formEndereco,
        }

    return render(request, 'appOrcamento/novo_cliente.html', context)
```

Espero que essa resposta possa ajudar aos iniciantes.

@Edilson, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Legal que conseguiu resolver. Só lia quesão agora  -verificar se você não tinha um str com conteúdo "None" seria minha sugestão  - mas é um problema que pode pegar quem tem mais anos de casa também.  A dica que fica quando tiver outro mistério parecido é usar o `pdb` - você coloca um break-point no código com "`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`" , submete o forumlário, e acompanha no debugger a execução linha a linha  - teria matado o problema na primeira sessão também.

Comment: @jsbueno, blza?  A dica do pdb é excelente, eu tentei usar, mas quando mando seguir o processamento ele gerava erro.  Ai fiquei na dureza do print.  O colega Edilson me sugeriu o type(), ai foi na mosca.  Perdemos um tempo, mas conseguimos.  Coloquei a resposta para ajudar a galera que está iniciando como eu.  Valeu pelo comentario, vou tentar usar o pdb novamente.  Agora eu te garanto, problemas com tipo de variáveis, nunca mais...rsrs